# Javascript copy to clipboard manually and onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following code. On click the Data item is copied to clipboard as needed but the problem is when I try to copy multiple items by selecting them and manually copying, it will only copy the first item that has been selected and not all.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // ------- code added from here -------
    this.className = 'copied';
    var td = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       td.className = '';
    }, 1000)
    // -------      up to here      -------
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

```css
td.copied:after {
content: "copied";
background-color: red;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

For example if you select all 3 Data items and ctrl-c or right click and copy it will only copy the first item that is selected.

While still keeping the click to copy is there something that can be changed in the code to fix this or would a checkbox/button that could be toggled on or off to enable/disable this function to allow copying multiple items be the best way of doing this?

A solution without using jQuery would be preferred.

Comment: Your code only captures the contents of the DOM element that was clicked on.  You need to look at `window.getSelection()` to find out what the user actually selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyones replies, it pointed me in the right direction.  Below is my solution.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");


tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // ------- code added from here -------
    this.className = 'copied';
    var td = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       td.className = '';
    }, 1000)
    // -------      up to here      -------
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
// ------- solution code here -------        
      if(window.getSelection().toString() == "")
      {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      }
      else
      {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", window.getSelection());
      }
// ------- end of solution code -------
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

```css
td.copied:after {
content: "copied";
background-color: red;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I added an if statement to check if anything was selected and if there was then it used window.getSelection() instead of td.textContent.

Answer (score 1):

In your code on this line:

```
event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
```

change `td.textContent` which is capturing only that one clicked TD and then text of this TD is copied to `window.getSelection()`. This function will catch all selected data and then all data will be copied.

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // ------- code added from here -------
    this.className = 'copied';
    var td = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       td.className = '';
    }, 1000)
    // -------      up to here      -------
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", window.getSelection());
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

But now, you must select data, which you want to copy as first. You can try it here: [https://jsfiddle.net/0h25dc7z](https://jsfiddle.net/0h25dc7z/2/)

Of course, there are many ways, how to achieve which you want and `window.getSelection()` is only one of them.